# Finding the inverse and the solution for NxN system of equations in "one" step.

Tags: matrices

This is cool... at least if I have it right.

Do I understand correctly that (using the gauss/Jordan method) Finding the RRef of

|A|I||x| ( Matix A augmented by the Identity Matrix augmented by |x|) will simultaneously yield the Inverse of |A| and the Solution vector?

Comment: Yes, it will.  You can augment it by as many vectors as you want and get solution vectors for them all.  In a sense, augmenting it with $I$ is using the basis vectors as the $x$'s and finding the solution vectors for each.